# Why is my IOS App built in Xcode 14.3 not showing up in settings for file access permissions?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I developed an app in Xcode 14.3 and one of its feature is to download pdf, when I click the pdf button it is downloading, but after that neither the document picker is showing up for me to save it in files nor is it being stored automatically.

Code in ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import MobileCoreServices // Add this import for document picker

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://developer.apple.com") // Replace with your website URL
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Request necessary permissions
        requestPermissions()
    }

    func requestPermissions() {
        // Request file provider domain usage permission
        let fileProviderDescription = "Permission to access files and folders"
        requestFileProviderDomainUsagePermissionIfNeeded(description: fileProviderDescription)

        // Request downloads folder usage permission
        let downloadsFolderDescription = "Permission to save downloaded files"
        requestDownloadsFolderUsagePermissionIfNeeded(description: downloadsFolderDescription)
    }

    func requestFileProviderDomainUsagePermissionIfNeeded(description: String) {
        let domainUsageAuthorized = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.<thiru.genik-1>") != nil

        if !domainUsageAuthorized {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Permission Required", message: description, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                self.openAppSettings()
            }))
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func requestDownloadsFolderUsagePermissionIfNeeded(description: String) {
        let downloadsFolderAuthorized = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first != nil
        if !downloadsFolderAuthorized {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Permission Required", message: description, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                self.openAppSettings()
            }))
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func openAppSettings() {
        guard let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else { return }
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsURL) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }

        if url.pathExtension.lowercased() == "pdf" {
            downloadPDF(from: url)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }

    func downloadPDF(from url: URL) {
        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (location, _, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to download PDF: \(error)")
                return
            }

            guard let location = location else {
                print("Invalid file location.")
                return
            }

            let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
            let destinationURL = documentsDirectoryURL?.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)

            do {
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURL!)
                print("PDF downloaded successfully: \(destinationURL?.path ?? "")")
                self.showDocumentPicker() // Show document picker after successful download
            } catch {
                print("Failed to save PDF: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func showDocumentPicker() {
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String], in: .import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Document picker delegate methods
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        // Handle the picked documents here
        // You can access the selected document using the `urls` parameter
        for url in urls {
            print("Picked document: \(url)")
        }
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        // Handle cancellation if needed
    }
}
```

code In info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array/>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryLimitedAccessAPISupport</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSFileProviderPresenceUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Permission to access files and folders</string>
    <key>NSDownloadsFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Permission to save downloaded files</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I tried to build an web app and from that I wanted to download a pdf file and save it in files.The file opens after downloading but it is not saved anywhere and the document picker is also not showing up.

I am a complete beginner and this is my first time trying to build an app in Xcode. I'm completely stuck and have no idea on what to do. Please help me crease this hurdle

Comment: Try to set the [directoryUrl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3183918-directoryurl) property of the picker view controller to your app document directory

Comment: This is an iOS app, there are no "file access permissions".